# How to duplicate Elementor page via code?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I created a plugin that clones a specific Wordpress page, this page that I will call original was created with Elementor.

When activating the plugin, the page is copied perfectly, but when I access this cloned page, it is not exactly the same as the original page in terms of layout, but when I open the cloned page in the Elementor edition, the page is the same, with the entire structure preserved.

I checked the "_postmeta" table, the meta_keys are the same as the original page, I have already compared the values, they are the same within the meta_value fields.

What's the secret? Why doesn't the page look the same when I access it? The layout looks different.

```
function duplicate_page_111_as_draft( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( 'sda_churches' === $post->post_type && $new_status === 'publish' && $old_status !== 'publish' ) {
        $original_post_id = 111; // ID of the page you want to duplicate
    
        // Get the original post data
        $post = get_post($original_post_id);
    
        // Set the new post author (optional, you can customize as needed)
        $new_post_author = $post->post_author;
    
        // Create an array with new post data
        $args = array(
            'comment_status' => $post->comment_status,
            'ping_status'    => $post->ping_status,
            'post_author'    => $new_post_author,
            'post_content'   => $post->post_content,
            'post_excerpt'   => $post->post_excerpt,
            'post_name'      => $post->post_name . '-copy', // You may want to adjust this to avoid conflicts
            'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
            'post_password'  => $post->post_password,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_title'     => $post->post_title . ' Copy', // You may want to adjust this to avoid conflicts
            'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
            'to_ping'        => $post->to_ping,
            'menu_order'     => $post->menu_order
        );
    
        // Insert the new post
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
    
        // Duplicate all post terms and set them to the new post draft
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type);
        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
            $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($original_post_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'slugs'));
            wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, $post_terms, $taxonomy, false);
        }
    
        // Duplicate all post meta in two SQL queries
        $post_meta_infos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id=$original_post_id");
        if (count($post_meta_infos) != 0) {
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) ";
            foreach ($post_meta_infos as $meta_info) {
                $meta_key = $meta_info->meta_key;
                if ($meta_key == '_wp_old_slug') continue;
                $meta_value = addslashes($meta_info->meta_value);
                $sql_query_sel[] = "SELECT $new_post_id, '$meta_key', '$meta_value'";
            }
            $sql_query .= implode(" UNION ALL ", $sql_query_sel);
            $wpdb->query($sql_query);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'duplicate_page_111_as_draft', 10, 3 );
```

I also checked something, that when I edit the cloned page, make a change and save and access the page, then it looks the same as the original page.

But I wanted to understand why the page doesn't stay the same during cloning, I didn't want to have to enter the page, change it and save it to make it work. as several clonings will be made during the site's operation.

Comment: If the content on the two pages is the same, but the styling is different, you may have discrepancies in the css or in the id values, class values, or html structure between the pages. Spend some time using browser right-click Inspect on the two pages side by side to figure this out. Fun? not really. But you can sort it out.

Comment: When I open the cloned page in the editor, it is perfect, but when I view the page it is broken, I believe the CSS is missing but as I said above, the metadata is all in the database.

Comment: I found out what the problem is. Every time a page is created in Elementor, a CSS file is also created in the "uploads/elementor/css" folder with this structure "post-111.css", when I clone the page ID 111 the new file is not created in that folder as Id of the new page. I will try to create a way to clone this file too.

Comment: I did it, I'm creating the CSS file in the folder with the name and structure appropriate to the new page ID, it solved it.

Comment: Yes, I guessed it was something like that. 